# Neo4j: Relationships from CSV imported extremely slow

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, graph-databases

I have some issues importing a large set of relationships (2M records) from a CSV file.

I'm running Neo4j 2.1.7 on Mac OSX (10.9.5), 16GB RAM.

The file has the following schema:

```
user_id, shop_id
1,230
1,458
1,783
2,942
2,123
```

etc.

As mentioned above - it contains about 2M records (relationships).

Here is the query I'm running using the browser UI (I was also trying to do the same with a REST call):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file://path/to/my/file.csv" AS relation
MATCH (user:User {id: relation.user_id})
MATCH (shop:Shop {id: relation.shop_id})
MERGE (user)-[:LIKES]->(shop)
```

This query takes ages to run, about 800 seconds. I do have indexes on :User(id) and :Shop(id). Created them with:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(id) 
CREATE INDEX ON :Shop(id)
```

Any ideas on how to increase the performance?

Thanks

Comment: What are your java heap settings in neo4j-wrapper.conf ? And set 1000 for periodic commit to test.

Comment: So 2 million relationships divided by 800 seconds is 2,500 records/sec, which doesn't seem so bad to me.  What are you trying to hit, and have you tried some of the 2.2 series data loading tools?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Heap memory is set to 4096Mb. With "USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000" - same results.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits 2.2 is not production ready yet. So I prefer staying on the latest stable version. The more so I'd like to avoid any separate tools for doing the import. I believe it can be faster. Imagine a set of 50M relationships (which is relatively small set for a big graph). With such performance it will take weeks to proceed.

Comment: I understand about 2.2.  @ChristopheWillemsen has a good suggestions for you, you should try them.  If you want really fast, you have to suspend transactions altogether, and jam that data in.   See this link:  http://jexp.de/blog/2013/05/on-importing-data-in-neo4j-blog-series/   Relevant quote: "For massive imports (...) transactional approach doesn’t yield good enough performance. To saturate the full write speed of a modern disk (e.g. SSD-Raids up to 500MB/s), it is necessary to skip transaction semantics and build up your initial datastore in an “raw” way using a batch-insertion mechanism."

Comment: So long story short, if you want absolute speed, you need to look at a batch-insertion method, and skip the transactions that come with LOAD CSV.

Comment: can you flip the direction? MERGE (shop)<-[:LIKES]->(user)

Comment: can you share the first 10 lines of your CSV file?

Comment: Change MERGE to CREATE

Comment: @MichaelHunger Flipping the direction didn't help. First 10 lines: 
user_id,shop_id
4766499,18495333
4766499,184841040
4766499,30151769
4766499,20473609
4766499,1552589229
4766499,509840961
4766499,600075134
4766499,10545817
4766499,21922111

Comment: Changing MERGE to CREATE doesn't work because I need unique relationships. Using CREATE UNIQUE is deprecated, and MERGE is the actual replacement.

Comment: Can you prefix your query with `profile` in the neo4j-shell and share the results

Comment: Running it with a prefixed `profile` fails with the following message: "PeriodicCommitInOpenTransactionException: Executing queries that use periodic commit in an open transaction is not possible". Though without `profile` it starts processing.

Comment: remove the `periodic commit` for profiling

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space before shop_id

try to run:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:test.csv" AS r 
return r.user_id, r.shop_id limit 10;
```

to see if it is loaded correctly. On your original data r.shop_id is null as the column name is `shop_id`

Also make sure that you didn't store the id's as numeric values in the first place, then you have to use `toInt(r.shop_id)`

Try to profile your statement in Neo4j Browser (2.2.) or in Neo4j-Shell.
Remove the `PERIODIC COMMIT` for that purpose and limit the rows:

```
PROFILE
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file://path/to/my/file.csv" AS relation
WITH relation LIMIT 10000
MATCH (user:User {id: relation.user_id})
MATCH (shop:Shop {id: relation.shop_id})
MERGE (user)-[:LIKES]->(shop)
```

Comment: There is no whitespace. I added it here for the sake of readability. I already tried returning a subset of data from csv (as you showed in your example), and it returns the data correctly. The ids are stored as strings, already checked that as well.